# Add same row and column to datable

Tags: c#, wpf

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
   foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
       {
          table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, typeof(string));
       }
```

I have one datable dt which have data I am creating one new Datatable and adding a column into that Datatable then my table looks like shown in below image

[image]

Now show in image column name as a number, fullname, address, date, and so on I also want to add that same column as data row but I don't know how can I add it is like data row.

And every time column name changes so when I am adding it on the Datatable table as column name I also need to add it is a data row.
Please help me to do that

Comment: Check out [Keiths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108161/2417602) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself using the below code

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DataRow firstRow = table.NewRow();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                names.Add(column.ColumnName);
                table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, typeof(string));
            }

            firstRow.ItemArray = names.ToArray();
            table.Rows.InsertAt(firstRow, 0);
```

And it works as I want and thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type of logic:- First Add row after that in that rows add a column

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(number, fullname, address, address);
```

Comment: But that number, fullname, address are dummy actually values different and may be more than 25 columns then how can I use this

Comment: you can use looping and pass dynamic parameter

Comment: for refrence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642049/how-to-add-new-datarow-into-datatable